# Calculating amperage in a current source

Tags: current, amperage, math

How do I determine the amperage at "?" based on the selected resistors in this current source?

[image: Topology]

[Falstad Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0A172%20128%2048%20128%2016%200%206%20240%20240%200%200%200.5%20Voltage%0AR%2032%2048%2032%2016%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0At%2096%20160%20128%20160%200%201%20-239.27727007133504%200.7227299286649602%20100%0Aw%20128%2048%20128%20144%201%0Ag%20128%20272%20128%20288%200%0Ar%2032%20208%2032%20240%200%201000%0Aw%2032%20240%2032%20272%200%0Ag%2032%20272%2032%20288%200%0Aw%2032%2048%2032%2080%200%0Aw%2032%20112%2032%20160%200%0Aw%2032%20160%2032%20208%200%0Aw%20128%20176%20128%20208%200%0Aw%20128%20208%20128%20240%200%0Aw%2032%20160%2096%20160%201%0A174%20224%20112%20240%20144%200%2010000%200.024800000000000003%20Resistance%0Aw%2032%2080%2048%2080%200%0Aw%2048%2080%2048%2096%200%0Aw%20128%20240%20128%20272%200%0Ax%2065%20183%2078%20186%200%2024%20?%0Ar%2032%2080%2032%20112%200%201000%0A)

[image: Current vs Impedance]

I took a bunch of measurements from the simulation and plotted them. I know that that transistor base to emitter voltage drop increases with current but I don't know how it factors in.

[image: Current vs Vbe]

Edit: can down-voters please comment why so I can either amend or not repeat the issue in future?

Comment: In the real world it will be a differential equation based on the Vbe transfer equation and the resistive divider parameter of your two resistors. Using Falstad to get an accurate prediction is as unwise as having a small signal transistor work with 240V at 30mA. Falstad is a basics-teaching-tool, for which it is great. It is, however, eminently not great at being spot on.

Comment: Absolutely, I wouldn't be putting 240V through a 3904 :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current through the '?' that you have highlighted is the same as the current through the base-emitter of the transistor.  The base-emitter of the transistor is a diode and that is the characteristic that you are seeing.  The base-emitter diode is effectively shorting out your 1k resistor, so determining the current through the base-emitter is difficult.  Do some reading about the [diode voltage-vs-current](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/diodes/real-diode-characteristics) to get a better idea of the causes of the curve you are observing.

A simple current source can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source) if that is the type of circuit that you are looking for:

[image: wikipedia]

If you are just looking to experiment to see where things go, I would suggest placing a static resistor where you have the pot and moving the pot as a variable resistor between the voltage divider and the gate so that you can more directly alter the current through the transistor.